# Edit timer number format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code like this:

```
private IEnumerator RunTimer(float time, int kind_of_function)
{
    var seconds = (int) time;
    while (time > 0)
    {
        yield return null;
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        if ((int) time != seconds)
        {
            // Update the text
            seconds = (int) time;
            timerText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
        }

        if (seconds == 0)
        {
        }
   }
}
```

How to change this output format: 0:00 In such a way that if the number of seconds was two-digit then it would look like 00, and if it was one-digit then 0?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need the format string `"{0:#0}:{1:#0}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said use one of

- `#0` where

  `0` means: I definitely want this digit always
  `#` means: I want this digit only if it is not `0` or is a significant `0`

  see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
- `D`

  which basically means: Only show significant decimals digits.

  Since you have int you could even also use `N` which usually includes digits after the comma

  see [Standard Numeric Format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)
- Simply do not define a special format at all.

  What you describe is what happens by default anyway if you simply used

  ```
  string.Format("{0}:{1}", seconds / 60, seconds % 60)
  ```

---

Then I would prefer [`$` string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which in my opinion is more flexible and better maintainable

```
timeText.text = $"{seconds / 60}:{seconds % 60}";
```

or with the formatter

```
timeText.text = $"{seconds / 60:#0}:{seconds % 60:#0}";
```

---

Though in my humble opinion you should stick to what you had. Doesn't it look way better?

---

Okey apparently what you actually wanted is not displaying the minutes at all if there are only seconds

```
var minutes = seconds / 60;
if(minutes > 0)
{
    timeText.text = $"{minutes}:{seconds % 60:#0}";
}
else
{
    timeText.text = $"{seconds:#0}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I really didn’t understand how to remove these dots ":". My function takes different values ​​of time. Suppose the function has the value 9. I want it to look like this (9, 8, 7, 6, ....). If the function received the value 12, then I want it to be like this - (12, 11, 10, 9, 8 ...)

Comment: Sorry, i just need do that stuff `timerText.text = Convert.ToString(seconds)`. But anyway thanks for the information!

Comment: Ah so you actually would like to remove the minutes? Could've mentioned that ;) see update

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerator RunTimer(float time)
{
    var seconds = (int) time;
    while (time > 0)
    {
        yield return null;
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        bool moreThanTenSec = time / 10 > 1;
        if ((int) time != seconds)
        {
            // Update the text
            seconds = (int) time;
            if (moreThanTenSec)
                timerText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
            else
                timerText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:0}", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
        }

        if (seconds == 0)
        {
        }
   }
```

Comment: That's the ugly way of simply using `#0` ;)